# Parsing rsync -i output to display only transfered file name, size, speed and time

Tags: bash, awk, grep, rsync

I would like to extract from `rsync -i` only the transfered:

- filenames
- size
- speed
- duration

I am using this command :

```
rsync -e ssh --rsync-path="sudo rsync" -azih --progress --delete-after
--delete-excluded --exclude=".*" --exclude=".*/" "$local_dir" "$host":"$remote_path" | egrep -A1 '<'
```

Which already outputs me something like this:

```
 <f.stpog... tools/file.sh
         22,561 100%   20.85MB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#1, to-chk=0/6)
```

So, the idea is to obtain a one line output like this:

```
tools/file.sh 22,561 100% 20.85MB/s 0:00:00
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably to use a combination of `xargs` and `cut` like so.

```
rsync -e ssh --rsync-path="sudo rsync" -azih --progress --delete-after --delete-excluded --exclude=".*" --exclude=".*/" "$local_dir" "$host":"$remote_path" | egrep -A1 '<' | xargs -n8 | cut -d' ' -f2-6
```

`xargs -n8` will split your output to only have 8 items per line (assuming this is known and consistent), and `cut -d' ' -f2-6` will print the second to sixth character.  On a test file with your output this works.

```
$ cat testrsync
<f.stpog... tools/file1.sh
        22,561 100%   20.85MB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#1, to-chk=0/6)
<f.stpog... tools/file2.sh
        21,230 100%   21.22MB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#1, to-chk=0/6)
<f.stpog... tools/file3.sh
        43,340 100%   20.34MB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#1, to-chk=0/6)

$ cat testrsync | xargs -n8 | cut -d' ' -f2-6
tools/file1.sh 22,561 100% 20.85MB/s 0:00:00
tools/file2.sh 21,230 100% 21.22MB/s 0:00:00
tools/file3.sh 43,340 100% 20.34MB/s 0:00:00
```

Comment: Thanks Alex for your feedback, unfortunatly the number of row is not consistent, I will check in which situation the output change. I guess I will have to process the output in several steps.